# SQL SELF and INNER JOINS in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL database with three tables: department, role, and employee. The employee table has foreign keys to reference primary keys in both the department and role tables, as well as other employee primary keys in its own table. I currently have two separate queries to access the information I need, one using two INNER JOINS to access the department and role tables, and one using a SELF JOIN.

```
SELECT employee.id
     , employee.first_name
     , employee.last_name
     , role.title
     , role.salary
     , department.name AS Department 
  FROM employee 
  JOIN role 
    ON employee.role_id = role.id 
  JOIN department 
    ON role.department_id = department.id;

SELECT A.id
     , A.first_name
     , A.last_name
     , CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) As Manager 
  FROM employee A
     , employee B 
 WHERE A.manager_id = B.id 
 ORDER 
    BY A.id;
```

I would like the result to include the columns: employee.id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name, role.title, role.salary, department.name AS Department, and CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) AS Manager.

Is there a way I can combine these two queries into one query?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Could you add the schema of the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data and the schema of the tables it is a bit hard to replicate but... on first look I will give a shot in the dark with this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.first_name, A.last_name, role.title, 
       role.salary, department.name AS Department, 
       CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) As Manager  
FROM employee A
JOIN employee B ON A.manager_id = B.id
JOIN role ON A.role_id = role.id 
JOIN department ON role.department_id = department.id
ORDER BY A.id;
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped clear up my understanding of JOINS within a table which was causing me trouble in how to combine them with JOINS to other tables.

Comment: It will be better to name your tables better in future. Things like "A" and "B" are hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

That is as simple as additional join

It is easiest to keep track with more verbose names.

```sql
SELECT employee.id,
       employee.first_name,
       employee.last_name,
       role.title,
       role.salary,
       department.name AS Department,
       CONCAT(manager.first_name, ' ', manager.last_name) AS Manager
FROM employee
         JOIN role
              ON employee.role_id = role.id
         JOIN department
              ON role.department_id = department.id
         JOIN employee as manager
              ON employee.manager_id = manager.id;
```